# An algorithm to find the minimum price of a cart after apply discounts

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have to calculate the minimum price of a cart after apply discounts.

A customer can buy books of a series. This series has 5 different books. Each book cost 8€. But if you buy two different bookies in the series, you've got a 5% discount. If you buy 3 different books in the series, you've got a 10% discount. If you buy 4 different books in the series, you've got 20% discount. And if you buy all books of the series you've got a 25% discount.

An example of how much does this basket of books cost?

- 2 copies of the first book
- 2 copies of the second book
- 2 copies of the third book
- 1 copy of the fourth book
- 1 copy of the fifth book

The correct answer is: 51.20€

To get this final price you have to group the books in two blocks of 4 different books. So, 8 * 4 = 32 - 20% = 25.60€ * 2 = 51.20€

I have try to resolve with backtracking but I'm not able to find a correct solution.

How can I write the correct algorithm in JavaScript?

**Edit I:**

Following the wise advice of @visleck I have developed a possible solution who works fine always except in one case. At least, I have no found more cases where it doesn't work.

First of all, a function initializing all the options with his cost after discount applied:

```
    const PRICE = 8.00;
    export const initArray = (cart) => {
        var dp = [];

        var basket = [];
        basket[0] = typeof cart.get(1) !== "undefined" ? cart.get(1) : 0;
        basket[1] = typeof cart.get(2) !== "undefined" ? cart.get(2) : 0;
        basket[2] = typeof cart.get(3) !== "undefined" ? cart.get(3) : 0;
        basket[3] = typeof cart.get(4) !== "undefined" ? cart.get(4) : 0;
        basket[4] = typeof cart.get(5) !== "undefined" ? cart.get(5) : 0;

        //If we buy zero books
        var aux = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], parseFloat(0).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);

        //If we buy only one book
        aux = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], parseFloat(PRICE).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], parseFloat(PRICE).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], parseFloat(PRICE).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], parseFloat(PRICE).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], parseFloat(PRICE).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);

        //If we buy two books
        aux = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 2 * 0.95).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);

        //If we buy three books
        aux = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 1, 0, 1, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 0, 1, 1, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 3 * 0.90).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);

        //If we buy four books
        aux = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0], parseFloat(PRICE * 4 * 0.80).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 4 * 0.80).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 1, 0, 1, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 4 * 0.80).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[1, 0, 1, 1, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 4 * 0.80).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);
        aux = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 4 * 0.80).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);

        //If we buy five books
        aux = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], parseFloat(PRICE * 5 * 0.75).toFixed(2)];    
        dp.push(aux);

        return [basket, dp];
    }

basket is the shopping cart and dp is an array of 32 position with all the posibilities.

Now, the function who try to find the best price called *checkOut*. This function, call to other two: *solution* and *validSolution*

/**
 * Returns true if aux can be belongs to a possible finale solution, otherwise returns false
 * 
 * @param { array } basket 
 * @param { array } si 
 * @param { array } aux 
 */
export const solution = (basket, si, sol) => {
    var ps = [...sol];
    if (si.length > 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < si.length; i++){
            for (var j = 0; j < ps.length; j++){
                 ps[j] = parseInt(si[i][j] + ps[j]);
            }    
        }
    }    
    for (var i = 0; i < basket.length; i++){
        if (parseInt(basket[i] - ps[i]) < 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

export const validSolution = (basket, si) => {
    var aux = [...basket];
    for (var i = 0; i < si.length; i++){
        var sol = si[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < aux.length; j++){
            aux[j] = parseInt(aux[j] - sol[j]);
        }
    }
    var distinctZero = aux.filter(item => item > 0);
    return distinctZero.length == 0 ? true : false;
}

export const checkOut = (cart) => {
    const [basket, dp] = initArray(cart);
    var voa = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    var value = 0;
    var soa = [];
    var si = [];
    var level = 1;
    var i = 1;
    while (level < Math.pow(2, 5)){
        var aux = dp[i][0];
        if (solution(basket, si, aux)){
            si.push(aux);
            value = (value * 10 + dp[i][1] * 10)/10;
            i = level;
        }else if (i < (Math.pow(2, 5) - 1)){
            i++
        }else{
            level++;
            i = level;
            si = [];
            value = 0;
        }
        if (validSolution(basket, si)){
            if (value < voa){
                voa = value;
            }
            soa.push([si, value]);
            value = 0;            
            si = [];
            level++;
            i = level;            
        }
    }
    console.log(voa);
    // //console.log(soa);
    // console.log(soa[8][0][1]);
    // for (var i = 0; i < soa.length; i++){
    //     console.log(soa[i])
    // }

    return voa;
}
```

Whith these code, If I pass this tests all works fine:

```
var cart = new Map();
cart.set(1, 2);
cart.set(2, 2);
cart.set(3, 0);
cart.set(4, 0);
cart.set(5, 0);
assert.ok(parseFloat(30.40).toFixed(2) === parseFloat(checkOut(cart)).toFixed(2));
cart.set(1, 2);
cart.set(2, 2);
cart.set(3, 2);
cart.set(4, 1);
cart.set(5, 1);
assert.ok(parseFloat(51.20).toFixed(2) === parseFloat(checkOut(cart)).toFixed(2));
cart.set(1, 2);
cart.set(2, 0);
cart.set(3, 2);
cart.set(4, 0);
cart.set(5, 0);
assert.ok(parseFloat(30.40).toFixed(2) === parseFloat(checkOut(cart)).toFixed(2));
cart.set(1, 0);
cart.set(2, 0);
cart.set(3, 2);
cart.set(4, 0);
cart.set(5, 0);
assert.ok(parseFloat(16.00).toFixed(2) === parseFloat(checkOut(cart)).toFixed(2));
cart.set(1, 0);
cart.set(2, 0);
cart.set(3, 0);
cart.set(4, 1);
cart.set(5, 1);
assert.ok(parseFloat(15.20).toFixed(2) === parseFloat(checkOut(cart)).toFixed(2));
cart.set(1, 1);
cart.set(2, 1);
cart.set(3, 1);
cart.set(4, 1);
cart.set(5, 1);
assert.ok(parseFloat(30.00).toFixed(2) === parseFloat(checkOut(cart)).toFixed(2));
```

But with this test, fails:

```
cart.set(1, 2);
cart.set(2, 1);
cart.set(3, 1);
cart.set(4, 1);
cart.set(5, 1);
assert.ok(parseFloat(38.00).toFixed(2) === parseFloat(checkOut(cart)).toFixed(2));
```

The value returned is 43.20 and not 38.00 which is the correct value.

If I change this piece of code:

```
if (solution(basket, si, aux)){
    si.push(aux);
    value = (value * 10 + dp[i][1] * 10)/10;
    i = 1;
```

Making i = 1 and not i = level, then it works fine, but the previous cases doesn't work.

How can I improve my code so that it passes all the tests?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Try starting at the top(highest percentage), check if they have all books, if so, apply 25%. Check if they have 4 books, then 3, then 2.

Comment: I have tried to do it like you say, but I've not get the minimum price. According with the example. I have find a solution who groups the books in two blocks. One of them of 5 books (5 * 8 = 40€ - 25% = 30€) and other block of 3 books (5 * 8 = 24 - 10% = 21.6€). Therefore, the final cost of the cart would be 30€ + 21.6€ = 51.60€. And this is not the lowest value, because the lowest value you've got with two blocks of four books, 51.20€

Comment: All the discounts are applicable right? I mean it’s not required that only one discount is applicable in one cart.

Comment: Yes, so just remove the books from the calculation and start again

Comment: Hi, @RahulRaut!!! Yes, all the discounts are applicable to one cart.

Comment: So if you find a series, apply 25% to that price of books and then start again checking for the highest applicable discount without the previous books.

Comment: @ZacharyMcGee Doesn't work this way because of the cuts structure. 
`5 * 0.75 + 3 * 0.90 > 4 * 0.8 + 4 * 0.8`

Comment: @ZacharyMcGee I have done this and I don't get the lowest price with this strategy. In the post you can see that the lowest prices is getting applying two discounts of 20%.

Comment: @JoséCarlos Start with finding the optimum solution for two sets of books top. For 2-1-1-1-1, that's obvious; for 2-2-2-1-1, far less so. Then, when the optimum solutions are found for each set of two lines, consider how adding another one changes the picture.

Comment: @JoséCarlos Okay, I see now, it's a little more complicated than what I first assumed. I am currently at work, I will try to solve after work if no one else does.

Comment: Hi @Mike. That's not the correct answer because the discounts applies over the books not all the cart

Comment: @raina77ow At first sight, the optimum solution is to make a group of 25% discount, but how you can see in the example, that's not works. Because to get the minimum price is better to apply 20% of discount over 4 books and other 20% over other 4 books.

Comment: Exactly, because it's cheaper to represent that combination. But what about 3-3-2-1-1? The real question is, is that possible to know that some combinations are by definition cheaper? For example, why don't you try to represent 5 books as `3 * 0.9 + 2 * 0.95`? )

Comment: Question from Exercism JS track: https://exercism.org/tracks/javascript/exercises/book-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a memoized recursion where the search space depends on the number of states possible for the book quantities.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(state, ds, price, memo={}){
  if (!state.some(x => x > 0))
    return 0
  if (memo.hasOwnProperty(state))
    return memo[state]
    
  let best = Infinity
  
  function g(st, count, i){
    if (i == st.length)
      return
    if (st[i] > 0){          
      let _st = st.slice()
      _st[i]--
      best = Math.min(
        best,
        count * price * ds[count] + f(_st, ds, price, memo)
      )
      g(_st, count + 1, i + 1)
    }
    g(st, count, i + 1)
  }

  g(state, 1, 0)
  
  return memo[state] = best
}

var price = 8
var ds = [1, 1, 0.95, 0.9, 0.8, 0.75]
var states = [
  [2, 2, 0, 0, 0], // 30.40
  [2, 2, 2, 1, 1], // 51.20
  [2, 0, 2, 0, 0], // 30.40
  [0, 0, 2, 0, 0], // 16
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], // 15.20
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], // 30
  [2, 1, 1, 1, 1] // 38
]

for (let state of states)
  console.log(`${ state }: ${ f(state, ds, price) }`)
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if it had some explanation.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar agreed. The code tries all the different states that can be achieved from the initial state until all book quantities are zero, while memoising the answers so as to return early from states that were previously seen.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to solve it using **dynamic programming**.

Here I am assuming that enough memory is available for use.

You can use a 5-dimensional array for this. Lets call it dp[a][b][c][d][e], where a represents max no of books of type 1, 'b' represents max no of books of type 2, and so on.

Let's initialize each state with some max value as flag which denotes that this value has not been calculated yet. So any state (lets say dp[a1][b1][c1][d1][e1]) stores the optimal way to buy 'a1' books of type 1, 'b1' books of type 2 and so on.

So at each state, lets say dp[a1][b1][c1][d1][e1], we have 32 ways to go to other state, which is as given below.

When selecting only one book at a time.

```
dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 8.0 + dp[a-1][b][c][d][e]

dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 8.0 + dp[a][b-1][c][d][e]

dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 8.0 + dp[a][b][c-1][d][e]

dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 8.0 + dp[a][b][c][d-1][e]

dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 8.0 + dp[a][b][c][d][e-1]
```

Selecting two books at a time.

```
dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 16*0.95 + dp[a-1][b-1][c][d][e]

dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 16*0.95 + dp[a-1][b][c-1][d][e]
```

and 8 more cases

Selecting three books at a time

```
dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 24*0.9 + dp[a-1][b-1][c-1][d][e]

dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 24*0.9 + dp[a-1][b-1][c][d-1][e]
```

and 8 more cases.

Selecting four books at a time

```
dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 32*0.8 + dp[a-1][b-1][c-1][d-1][e]

dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 32*0.8 + dp[a-1][b-1][c-1][d][e-1]
```

and 3 more cases.

Selecting five books at a time

```
dp[a][b][c][d][e] = 40*0.75 + dp[a-1][b-1][c-1][d-1][e-1]
```

Doing this keeping in mind about the boundary conditions that no books in any state can be less than 0 or can go more than the max number of its type.

So the pseudo code is as given below

```
A[max_a][max_b][max_c][max_d][max_e]=max_value
func(a,b,c,d,e) 
    if(a>0 && b>0 && c>0 && d>0 && e>0) 
        if(A[a][b][c][d][e]!=max_value) 
            return A[a][b][c][d][e]
        endif
        recursive calls to all 32 cases mentioned above 
    endif
    return max_value                  //this will be returned when boundary condition fails
endfunc
```

This is a top down approach. Hence call this function using **func(a,b,c,d,e)** where a,b,c,d and e represnts the number of books of type 1,2,3,4 and 5 respectively

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Sorry, but I'm blocked and I'm not able to see any solution :((((( Can you develop your solution for a more simplified scene like a customer buy: 2 copies of book 1 and 2 copies of book 2, for example? Thanks in advance for your apreciated help!!!

Comment: There is a problem. In javascript there is no multidimensional arrays. But, it seems to be a good response. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JoséCarlos how did you conclude there is no multidimensional array in JavaScript?

Comment: There is no multidimensional array like this dp[a][b][c][d][e], but you can do an array of arrays being this second the mutidimension, like this dp[[a, b, c, d, e]]. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JoséCarlos ah. I believe you can do either one. The declaration is different.

Comment: So, I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: @JoséCarlos here's a function that will create an arbitrary multi dimension array https://ideone.com/Brgx4X

Comment: Thanks for the function for multi dimension arrays

Comment: Hi @JoseCarlos 
I'm sorry for the late reply. Did you understand the solution. Should I explain that with an example.

Comment: Hi @visleck!!! Don't worry, please!!! I have almost understand the solution. I have made a development who works fine except in one case. :( I'm going to update my original post.

Comment: hi @visleck, I am resuscitating this conversation because I am trying to solve this problem too and I don't fully understand your answer. I'm not sure what the dp[a1]...dp[e1] represent, and what does each combination of that 5 dimensional array is giving me is also unclear. Can you please explain your answer further? I am pretty confused on this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you're over thinking this. I also have a strong suspicion we're all doing the same.

Let's take this one step at a time.

Your discount structure is:
1 book: 0%
2 books: 5%
3 books: 10%
4 books: 20%
5 books: 25%
...

Your non-linear discount is making this less of a math problem and more of a logic problem. There's still plenty of math, but the gap between 3 books and 4 books adds complexity that straight math won't cover. How do we fix that? We use a lookup table/array so we can use the amount of books in the series to determine the discount by index.

```
var discountsAvailable = [0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25, ...];
```

Actually, it would be easier math later on to build in the subtraction from 100%, so it becomes:

var discountsAvailable = [1, 0.95, 0.9, 0.8, 0.75, ...];

Then we just use the amount of books purchased in the series as the index.

```
var qty1 = 3;
var qty2 = 5;
discountsAvailable[qty1] == 0.9
discountsAvailable[qty2] == 0.75
```

We do this for each series independently to get the discount, as you would guess. In the case where someone buys 2 different "sets" of the same series, we can iterate over them multiple times to get different options and then choose which we want to use.

```
var tempTotal = [];
var average = Math.floor((qty1 + qty2 + ...)/numberOfSeries);
tempTotal[0] = discountsAvailable[qty1] * price * qty1;
tempTotal[0] += discountsAvailable[qty2] * price * qty2;
...
tempTotal[1] = tempTotal[average] * price * average;
...
```

Then do a loop to find the lowest value in tempTotal. You could probably loop through the calculations for tempTotal, too.

This is a basic example of of your {2x, 2x, 2x, 1x, 1x} example, so more logic and more calculations would be needed to determine {3x, 2x, 4x, 1x, 2x} as well as if there are more than 5 books in the series. Unfortunately, it gets much more convoluted when gets that complicated

Using your example:

```
average = (3 + 5) / 2; // 4  
tempTotal[0] = 0.9 * 8 * 3; // 21.6  
tempTotal[0] += 0.75 * 8 * 5; // 30  
tempTotal[0] == 51.6;  

tempTotal[1] = 0.8 * 8 * 4; // 51.2
```

The tempTotal[0] is 3 books out of 5 {1, 1, 1, 0, 0} plus 5 out of 5 books{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, while tempTotal[1] is 2x 4 books out of 5 {1, 1, 1, 1, 0} plus {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}.

So your answer is tempTotal[1] at 51.2.

Comment: Sorry, I think there is an error, because I don't say that there is a serie of 5 and 3 books. You buy 8 books, 2 copies of book1, 2 copies of book2, 2 copies of book3, 1 copy of book4 and 1 copy of book 5. Then, you have to get the best price, the minimum price and this is 51.20€. So, in average, I don't know how you get 3 and 5 and supose that the number of series are 2.

Comment: The user bought 8 books, but out of that, there's a set of 3 of 5 {1, 1, 1, 0, 0} and 5 of 5 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}. Split differently, it's 2 sets of 4 of 5 {1, 1, 1, 1, 0} and {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for anything other than trivial input, trying all the possibilities results in an exponential runtime that is impractical. While we can't theoretically reduce the runtime, we can practically do much better by identifying the search paths that can be pruned.

1. For this problem, *it only matters how many different types of books are there*. Instead of operating on the input array, we are going to be working with a frequency array. So, `[1, 1, 2]` becomes `[0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]`. The array is of size 6 for convenience, so, that we can use the books directly as indices without having to subtract 1.
2. A naive caching/memoization approach would use the frequency array directly as the key, but note that `[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]` and `[0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]` cost exactly the same. Thus, we will *use a sorted, non-zero, frequency array as the cache key*. In the above example, it is `[1, 2]`.
3. Lastly, note that `[1, 1]` (zeros removed) will produce three combinations, `[[1], [1], [1, 1]]`, of which the first two are identical. Thus, we will *deduplicate the combinations before iterating on them*.

I don't have JavaScript code but I solved the same problem on Exercism Rust track, which is where I assume you got it from. You can see [my solution here](https://exercism.org/tracks/rust/exercises/book-store/solutions/bruce-wayne).